Specify custom errorbar values in Seaborn
I have the following dataframe:
data = pd.DataFrame([
    ["A", "gelu", 0.896048951, 0.897377622, 0.893671329],
    ["A", "hard_tanh", 0.889965035, 0.891643357, 0.888566434],
    ["A", "leaky_relu", 0.89527972, 0.896818182, 0.89451049],
    ["A", "relu", 0.893811189, 0.896748252, 0.891853147],
    ["A", "tanh", 0.892272727, 0.894230769, 0.889685315],
    ["B", "gelu", 0.896048951, 0.897377622, 0.893671329],
    ["B", "hard_tanh", 0.889965035, 0.891643357, 0.888566434],
    ["B", "leaky_relu", 0.89527972, 0.896818182, 0.89451049],
    ["B", "relu", 0.893811189, 0.896748252, 0.891853147],
    ["B", "tanh", 0.892272727, 0.894230769, 0.889685315],
], columns=["mode", "act_fn", "accuracy", "y_err1", "y_err2"])


I'm trying to display it with a bar plot using seaborn, however no matter what I try I keep getting the error 'yerr' (shape: (2, 5)) must be a scalar or a 1D or (2, n) array-like whose shape matches 'y' (shape: (1,)) or similar, how should I proceed? This is the code I'm using:
sns.barplot(
            data=data,
            x="act_fn",
            y="accuracy",
            hue="mode",
            # yerr=tmp_df[["y_err1", "y_err2"]].to_numpy().T, # this doens't work even if I remove the hue and try to display only mode A
            ax=ax,
)

Also I imagine I would have to compute y_err1 and y_err2 as values relative to accuracy and not absolute ones, but just getting the errorbars to plot would be great!

You must use https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html to add error bars. Additionally, yerr should be a value +/- the top of the bar, not absolute positions of the error bar endpoints. top = yerror2 - accuracy and bottom = accuracy - yerror1

@JohanC between the duplicates and my comment, there may be enough information for the op to resolve the issue. However, because y_err1 and y_err2 are not +/- values, but absolute endpoints, I don’t think the duplicates alone adequately solve the issue.

Sorry, it should be top = yerror1 - accuracy and bottom = accuracy - yerror2

The errorbars are meant to be calculated by seaborn from the orignal data.  If these aren't available, there are many similar questions:  Use Precalculated Error Bars, factor plot custom error bars instead of bootstrapping, How to plot errorbars on seaborn barplot, How can custom errorbars be aligned on grouped bars?, ...

Thank you for all the comments. I have solved by manually adding error bars on top of the graph, however my question was mostly caused by the weird error messsage: the shape i pass to y is (5,) which would match the values given to yerr, while when I call the plotting, I get that y is (1,). Why is that?

@Luka The error message comes from matplotlib.  Seaborn prepares the data for custom plotting, and passes all unused parameters (keywords) to the matplotlib plotting function.  As seaborn calls the matplotlib function for specific subsets, or sometimes just a single bar, the correspondence is wrong. That is what is meant by kwargs: key, value mappings - Other parameters are passed through to matplotlib.patches.Rectangle in the sns.barplot documentation. Seaborn prefers to calculate the errorbars from the original data.
